# Firebase database notifications

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an iOS app that I am working on and every time I change anything in the firebase db it notifies my app.  I am looking to stop all those notifications as I want to implement notifications myself and just have firebase be a datastore.

I am using .observeSingleEvent everywhere but the app still gets notified every time the DB updates.

As you probably guessed I am new to Firebase but I was hoping some knowledgeable firebase person can help explain to me how to turn off all firebase notifications.

**IMPORTANT:**  I do need to have the capability to do my own push notifications so I cannot simply stop the iOS App from registering for notifications.  Right now Firebase and my notifications conflict and I get duplicates.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What do you mean as `notifies`? The push notifications or the result of `.observeEvent`?

Comment: Well, two part i guess.  I have an iOS app and I created a push notification.  But also, in Firebase, if I go to the console and change an item it updates another item as well as sends a push to my device.  So I cannot find where in firebase the rules (or whatever) is telling firebase to change the other table in the console.  And also notifiy my app. - Does that make sense?

Comment: .observeSingleEvent is just that, a single event. It fires one time and no more. If you are receiving events from Firebase, then you have added an observer elsewhere in the app, and that observer has a closure that handles the incoming event. Where that is, we don't know but if you do a Project Find in XCode and search for .observe, you will find where it is.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to make a firebase fire a push notification when node is changed. You should check [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/?authuser=1). There must be an information about when fire and what to change.

Comment: Cloud functions have nothing to do with Firebase Database notifications in an app.